# create/join pthread in same loop

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I have an array called doneArray that I store 1's in when a thread is finished. For example, in thread 4 right before I call `pthread_exit`, I set doneArray[4] to 1. So I can run through doneArray to see if a given thread has finished.

In this loop in my `main()` code, I create a thread, then check if any threads have finished. If they do, I join them. The resulting behavior is crazy at times and doesn't work the same as if I had a separate join loop.

```
   for(long i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){

      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, body, (void*) i);

      sleep(random() % 5 + 1);

      //the loop that creates new threads should join threads that have finished
      for(int j = 0; j < numberOfThreads; j++){
         if(doneArray[j] == 1){
            pthread_join(threads[j], &retval);
         }
      }

   }
```

My instructor has told us to do the `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` in the same loop or we will lose points. I'm very confused, because I have previously been taught NOT to do this, and other answers I've seen on this website have been also saying to do the join in a separate loop:

`If we put the pthread_join() in the same loop with pthread_create(), the calling thread i.e. main() will wait for the thread 0 to finish its work before creating the thread 1. This would force the threads to execute sequentially, not in parallel. Thus it would kill the purpose of multi-threading.`

Comment: Either your instructor needs to clarify WTH they're talking about, or you need to find another instructor. That `doneArray[j] == 1` madness is a bag of hammers all on it's own, as it has no concurrency protection (that we can see), and will predictably invoke `pthread_join` on already-joined threads in the latter loops of `i`. Either way, you're correct to question the sanity of their mandate.

Comment: the only concurrency protection that I have is that the contents of doneArray are set to 1 within a mutex lock, but that does little to advance the argument as all your other points are valid points

Comment: Even if you set it under the protection of a mutex, you don't *check* it *here* under the protection of the same mutex. That was the ultimate reason I brought it up in the first place. Regardless, the sanity of any of this is questionable, as you've noticed. You gain little to proactively join prior, expiring threads in the same loop as starting new ones. Such a montage *begs* for a better solution (perhaps a work queue or crew model). There must be some reason *why* the instructor wants this. Does no one in the class have sufficient brass to *ask* ?

Comment: Assuming there are no other threads in the process, the code you posted is exactly equivalent to `for(long i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) { body( ( void * ) i ); }`   Either you're not understanding your instructor's direction, or your instructor is utterly clueless.  Because you're right - there is absolutely no point in a single loop that on each loop iteration spawns one child thread and then waits on it to finish

Comment: If the number of threads does not exceed your machine word width, the `doneArray` could be stored in an atomic. AFAIK, atomics are usually significantly faster than mutex guarded variables. ([C11 Atomic Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic))

Comment: I asked myself if an array of `atomic_flag`s would work as well. I googled a while without finding any pro or con. Finally, I read a note about a fix: _Apart from that, the \_Atomic (type-name) syntax is implemented.  The tests for applying _Atomic qualifiers to function or array types are fixed._ (concerning gcc) in [C11-atomic - Miscellaneous fixes 1/n](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-10/msg01415.html). So, it seems there's nothing bad about this that this isn't even mentioned anywhere (else).

Comment: Sidenote: In general, casting a long to void* is not a good idea. It may work on 64-bit Unix OS:es since they are LP64, i.e. longs and pointers are both 64 bits long. Windows is for example LLP64, so long is 32 bits on 64-bit Windows. (long long is 64 bits)

Comment: @WhozCraig There is no harm in joining a thread more than one time. The first call will wait if necessary for the thread to die. All subsequent calls will return immediately.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, depends what that `sleep()` call is supposed to represent. Maybe the instructor meant it to be a stand-in for some function that would have done some actual work in some real program.  It _can_ make sense to spawn a thread, _do some work_, and then join the thread. Of course, if you're doing that in a loop, in a real program, then you probably should be using a thread _pool_; but that probably is a topic for a later lesson.

Comment: @jameslarge *There is no harm in joining a thread more than one time.*  There most certainly is if thread ids get reused.

Comment: Oh Foo! You're right.  I misread [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).  It says that joining a thread that previously has been joined is UB.